# Why TVs / laptops etc. do not warn about too brirght screen whereas many smartphones warn about too loud sound amplification?

Tags: civil-law

I'm trying to comfortably use my laptop at night and now could not find an answer by web-search to the following: Why TVs / laptops etc. do not warn about too bright screen whereas many smartphones warn about too loud sound amplification? I'm asking on law site cause I suspect there were a number of successful lawsuits for impaired hearing from headphones but none for impaired vision from TVs. Am I right here? Digging down - has it happened because there are studies proving impairment for one and none for the other?

Added: I actually doubt my second guess cause there are a lot of enhancements in screen brightness - auto-brightness, night mode.

Comment: Because Earthlings will not suffer visual impairment from any setting of a reasonably set range of brightness, in fact, certain screens achieves a higher brightness setting by increasing the refreshing rate and lower frequency refreshing correlates with sight loss.

Comment: Sorry, welcome on the site! Genuinely is intended as harmless banter! :)

Comment: @kisspuska, I recall there are guidelines for work settings for minimal lightning so there were issues with low brightness, it is my guess too high brightness might be detrimental too.

Comment: @Martian2020 *Low contrast* is an ergonomics issue because it makes screen contents hard to read. Better contrast can be achieved in two ways: by making the screen brighter, or by making the environment darker. The sun is very bright, so ergonomics guidelines require direct sunlight to be prevented. Older screen tech such as CRTs also really benefitted from darker rooms. Modern laptop screens with 200 to 400 nits are perfectly fine in a variety of settings. Of course, you might find lower brightness sufficient for comfortable contrast.

Comment: @amon, I see, however, hasn't been noticed also issue of too high contrast? in pitch-dark room even lowest brightness setting of particular device may be too high contrast...

Comment: @Martian2020 Your questions don't really sound like they're legal questions.

Comment: @Sneftel, in general I would agree questions in comments are not direct legal, but I think they are still related to starting one because in a court of law one should prove causality of impairment to win tort claim. In comments I only reply to other's thoughts on causality.

Comment: This is more of a user-interface or UX question. See https://ux.stackexchange.com/
I suspect the warning about loud noise is to enhance UX, not necessarily to avoid lawsuits.  Probably many users have experienced sometimes accidentally hitting the volume control and making the sound too loud, which is just not a nice experience, regardless of whether it caused damage or not.  The UX designers evidently thought that a warning for this would improve the UX. On the other hand, I doubt anyone has experienced accidentally getting blinded by a bright screen. It's just a non issue in UX.

Comment: Also I see this specific UX issue was discussed some time ago. It is not really a legal issue at all, purely a UX one. https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/41495/is-obstructive-behaviour-in-order-to-protect-a-users-health-considered-good-ux

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Because there is no evidence that screens damage vision

There is copious research on this phenomenon and while screens can cause short term problems like eye irritation and headaches, these are self-evident and temporary. There is simply no evidence that screens cause long term damage to the eyes (for [example](https://www.nature.com/articles/eye2015261)).

### There is strong evidence that loud noise can damage hearing

Hearing loss is a function of the volume of the noise and the duration of exposure (for [example](https://whitecathearing.com/when-is-sound-dangerous)).

Headphones are often worn for prolonged periods and can easily be louder than 80dB which is generally considered the threshold for hearing loss risk.

Comment: In addition to eye irritation and headaches, there is growing awareness of the impact on sleep.  Sleep deprivation may have long-term and even permanent deleterious effects, but the relationship isn't as obvious nor as direct.  Furthermore even if the relationship were well established, it would be difficult to show in an individual case that someone's heart disease was caused by screen-induced sleep deprivation.